# Помогите разобраться с шаблонами Django!

Tags: python, django

```
<h4>Books:</h4>
{% for book in author.book_set.all %}
{{book}},
{% endfor %}
```

> Собственно на сайте отображается вот так:
>   Но я хочу что бы после последней книги была точка!!!Как этого добиться?не первый раз сталкиваюсь,решил спросить!Спасибо[image: Но я хочу что бы после последней книги была точка!!!Как этого добиться?не первый раз сталкиваюсь,решил спросить!Спасибо]

Comment: `{% if forloop.last %}.{% else %}, {% endif %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, у цикла `for` есть ряд переменных, доступных в цикле, и как уже написал [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) можно использовать значение `forloop.last`.

> `forloop.last` - вернёт `True` если текущая итерация является последней в цикле `for`

Полезная ссылка для ознакомления: [**`for`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for), там же можно почитать про переменные доступные в цикле:

- `forloop.counter` - текущая итерация цикла (начиная от 1)
- `forloop.counter0` - текущая итерация цикла (начиная от 0)
- `forloop.revcounter` - количество интераций с конца цикла (начиная от 1)
- `forloop.revcounter0` - количество интераций с конца цикла (начиная от 0)
- `forloop.first` - вернет True если текущая итерация является первой
- `forloop.last` - вернет True если текущая итерация является последней
- `forloop.parentloop` - родительский цикл (для вложенных циклов)

Ну, собственно говоря получится такой код:

```
{% for book in author.book_set.all %}
    {{book}}{% if forloop.last %}.{% else %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ну и еще одна полезная ссылка: [Django template for loop - Last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837258/5275890)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!